# Angular2 *ngFor: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: arrays, json, object, angular, ngfor

I trying to get data from a JSON file to build a form.

Here is a portion of my template:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="power">Power</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
      <option *ngFor="let p of heroes" [value]="p.level">{{p.level}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here is part of the remote JSON file:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "level": "newbie",
            "places": [
                {
                    "place": "earth",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "category": "human",
                            "values": [
                                ...
```

It works with no problem and i get `newbie` and other choices in the `select` menu.
But i want to loop on places, so i edit the html template in this way:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="power">Power</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
      <option *ngFor="let p of heroes[0].places" [value]="p.place">{{p.place}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here is the service that i use to grab data from JSON file:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    private url = 'app/mockups/heroes.json';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
            .catch();
    }
}
```

and here is the `hero.component`:

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[];

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.getHeroes();
}

    getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
```

But i get **"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"** error.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I got this error because I'm fetching data asynchronously and when Angular tries to resolve bindings the first time data is still null therefore `heroes[0]` fails.

So I solved the problem initializing `heroes` array and using the "Elvis operator":

`heroes: Hero[];` instead of `heroes: Hero[] = [];` in the component.

`heroes[0]?.places` instead of `heroes[0].places` in the html template.

Comment: Could you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906983/how-to-get-array-value-of-key-from-rest-call-response-in-angular-js

Comment: @smartmouse heroes: Hero[]; instead of heroes: Hero[]; in the component. 
same value instead of same value, I am confused.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [Gunter said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39344062/542251)?

Answer (score 14):

I guess what you want is

```
*ngFor="let p of heroes?.data"
```

because `heroes` seems to be an object, and `ngFor` can only iterate array.
The `level` property also is in an array item.

Comment: Yes, that `heroes` in the html template loops on `data` array. Now i want to loop on `data[0].places` array, where `[0]` is the first object of `data` array.

Comment: That wasn't obvious from your question. I guess the error is caused by the code that assigns the json to `heroes`.

Comment: According to your update "Yes, that heroes in the html template loops on data array. " doesn't seem to be true. Did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, i loop on `data` array because i can see items in the output. I get it from service (`.then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])`). For this reason you code doesn't work.

Comment: Then the JSON you posed in the question is not exactly what you assign to `heroes`

Comment: Have you tried `[value]="p?.place"` instead of `[value]="p.place"`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @Gunter Zochbauer's solution, you can declare `heroes`as Array property of suitable type. If you have any class with all attributes of `heroes` you declare `heroes` property as:

```
heroes:Array<Heroes> //Assuming class name is Heroes
```

And initialize it in constructor as follows:

```
constructor(){
...    
this.heroes=new Array<Heroes>();
}
```

And in your ngFor loop simply access class attributes as follows:

```
<option *ngFor="let p of heroes" [value]="p.place">{{p.place}}</option>
```

Hope it helps.