# How to loop on array coming from asynchronous call to remote JSON file?

Tags: arrays, json, asynchronous, angular, angular-promise

I trying to get data from a JSON file to build a form.

Here is a portion of my template:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="power">Power</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
      <option *ngFor="let p of heroes" [value]="p.level">{{p.level}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here is part of the remote JSON file:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "level": "newbie",
            "places": [
                {
                    "place": "earth",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "category": "human",
                            "values": [
                                ...
```

It works with no problem and i get `newbie` and other choices in the `select` menu.

Now i want to loop on `places`, so i edit the html template in this way:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="power">Power</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
      <option *ngFor="let p of heroes[0].places" [value]="p.place">{{p.place}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

As you can see i used `heroes[0].places` instead of `heroes` to enter the `places` array that is a property of the first item in `heroes` array.

Here is the service that i use to grab data from JSON file:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    private url = 'app/mockups/heroes.json';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getHeroes(): Promise<Array<Object>> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Array<Object>)
            .catch();
    }
}
```

and here is the `hero.component`:

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Array<Object>;

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.getHeroes();
}

    getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
```

But i get **"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"** error.

I think this happens because i'm fetching data by asynchronous way and when Angular tries to resolve bindings the first time data is still null therefore heroes[0] fails. For this reasons I even tried to add the `Elvis operator` in the loop (`let p of heroes[0]?.places`), but i get the same error.
So, how to loop on array that contains data that is coming from asynchronous call?

Comment: Follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343980/angular2-ngfor-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined/39344062?noredirect=1#comment66059585_39344062

Comment: I finally solved initializing the array: `heroes` in the component (i also updated the answer in that question)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `async` pipe? If not, please refer code snippet below:

```
*ngFor="let p of heroes[0].places | async " [value]="p.place"
```

Comment: Is that for my case? I get `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/hero.component.js class HeroComponent - inline template:0:212 caused by: Cannot read property 'ambiti' of undefined`