# How to get array value of key from rest call response in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am making a rest call in angular js. I am able to get simple key value from response. But when key's value in array form then I am not able to get value in angular js controller.

I am sharing my related code(Not Same).

```
Rc.all('demo/example/db/').get('quues/').then(function(res)
  {
   $scope.demo={}
   $scope.demo.details={         
     value1 : res.Ksus.Type.Master.Origin.ID,        
       }

 $scope.array={}
   $scope.array.arrValue={         
     arrVal : res.Asus[0].AsuID,        
       }
   }
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  _id:123
  Ksus: {
       Type: {
       Master: {
         Origin: {
                  ID: "Demo"
                }
              }
            }
       },
 Asus: [{
     AsuID: "f4",
     Type: "SU",     
     }]
}
```

I want to get **AsuID** value in controller. I am able to get simple key value without array in controller like  **ID: "Demo"**. But I want to get array value. When I tried  **arrVal : res.Asus[0]**,   Then It is give **0** undefined value in console. Please give some idea for this thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run `console.log(res)` in your callback function and paste the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are referencing `res` outside the `get` method.
Below code will give you the required data.

```
 Rc.all('demo/example/db/').get('quues/').then(function(res)
  {
   $scope.demo={}
       $scope.demo.details={         
          value1 : res.Ksus.Type.Master.Origin.ID,        
       }
       $scope.array={}
       $scope.array.arrValue={         
          arrVal : res.Asus[0].AsuID,        
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think your sample code is same as me. No Difference. I corrected my code.

Comment: Okay, Looks like you corrected it now.
Before `$scope.array.arrValue={         
          arrVal : res.Asus[0].AsuID,        
       }` block was outside the `get` method.

Comment: Are you still getting `undefined` ?

Comment: Can you please log `res.Asus` and show me the output ?

Comment: Or console.log `res` itself.

Comment: Can I use for loop instead of hard code index value in 0.

Comment: I can say that by seeing the console.log(res);
You can use loop as well.

Comment: For that I need to see the JSON.
Can you paste output of `res` ?

Comment: That's not the exact JSON.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906983/how-to-get-array-value-of-key-from-rest-call-response-in-angular-js/45907703?noredirect=1#comment78783861_45911769 

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45911769/revisions

Comment: I am new in this. I want to only standard syntax for getting array json. thanks your effort. And save my time.

Comment: You got the solution or still facing the issue ?

Comment: I got it. But i want to put in loop.

Answer (score 0):

FYI -

I am assuming `,` in your JSON response between _id and Ksus. After a closer look at your JSON response, your `Asus` key exists under `Type` -

JSON -

```
{
    _id: 123,
    Ksus: {
        Type: {
            Master: {
                Origin: {ID: "Demo"}
            },
            Asus: [{
                AsuID: "f4",
                Type: "SU"
            }]
        }
```

So to traverse the `AsuID` you need to do - `res.Ksus.Type.Asus[0].AsuID`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you check again?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `,` After `Type: "SU"`