# ngFor loop is hitting an undefined and stopping

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ngfor

*ngFor is hitting an undefined value and stopping, how do I tell it to keep going?
... when I take out
{{order.shipping.name}}
the other two interpolations work.

the component:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderService } from '../../order.service';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin-orders',
    templateUrl: './admin-orders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./admin-orders.component.css']
})
export class AdminOrdersComponent {
    orders$;

    constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {
        this.orders$ = orderService.getOrders();
    }

}
```

the template:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>

            <th class="text-center">id</th>
            <th class="text-right">id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div *ngFor="let order of this.orders$ | async: date">
                    {{order.shipping.name}}

                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div *ngFor="let order of this.orders$ | async">

                    {{order.datePlaced | date:"short"}}
                    <!-- https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe -->
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <div *ngFor="let order of this.orders$ | async">
                    <a> {{order.userId}} </a>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343980/angular2-ngfor-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined) and changed it to...

```
orders$: FirebaseListObservable<any>; in the component
```

{{order?.shipping.name}}    in the template

...with no luck

Comment: Why do you use `order?` in the first loop and not in the others?

Comment: forgot to take that out, it was leftover from my tests.... but now the problem is solved because I put the saafe operator in all of the loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another safe navigation operator after shipping as well,

```
 {{order?.shipping?.name}}
```

Comment: that did the trick! wont make that mistake again. you answered too quickly i cant give you the answer yet haha